# List of strings to binary matrix

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I would like to create a binary matrix based on a list of strings.

```
dt = data.table(id = c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6'), sample = c("MER-1,MER-3,MER-4","MER-5","MER-2","MER-2,MER-3,MER-4,MER-5","MER_3","MER-5" ))

dt
    id                  sample
1: id1       MER-1,MER-3,MER-4
2: id2                   MER-5
3: id3                   MER-2
4: id4 MER-2,MER-3,MER-4,MER-5
5: id5                   MER_3
6: id6                   MER-5
```

Should result in something like:

```
m_count = matrix(c(1,0,1,1,0, 0,0,0,0,1, 0,1,0,0,0, 0,1,1,1,1, 0,0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0,1), nrow = 6, ncol = 5)

m_count

    MER-1 MER-2 MER-3 MER-4 MER-5
id1     1     0     0     1     0
id2     0     0     0     1     0
id3     1     0     0     0     0
id4     1     1     0     0     0
id5     0     0     1     1     0
id6     0     1     1     0     1
```

I could loop over each element of the list, and fill the matrix, but given the size of my table that would be really slow. Is there any quicker/more elegant way to go? Maybe with dplyr/tidyverse ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the `strsplit`:

```
table(dt[,unlist(strsplit(sample,",")),by=id])
     V1
id    MER-1 MER-2 MER-3 MER-4 MER-5 MER_3
  id1     1     0     1     1     0     0
  id2     0     0     0     0     1     0
  id3     0     1     0     0     0     0
  id4     0     1     1     1     1     0
  id5     0     0     0     0     0     1
  id6     0     0     0     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `dt` from the Note at the end which fixed the typo in the question, use `separate_rows` to expand the data row by row and then use `table` to compute the counts.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt %>%
  separate_rows(sample, sep = ",") %>%
  table
```

giving:

```
     sample
id    MER-1 MER-2 MER-3 MER-4 MER-5
  id1     1     0     1     1     0
  id2     0     0     0     0     1
  id3     0     1     0     0     0
  id4     0     1     1     1     1
  id5     0     0     1     0     0
  id6     0     0     0     0     1
```

### Note

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(id = c('id1','id2','id3','id4','id5','id6'), 
  sample = c("MER-1,MER-3,MER-4","MER-5","MER-2","MER-2,MER-3,MER-4,MER-5","MER-3","MER-5" ))
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use the library `splitstackshape`:

```
table(cSplit(dt, "sample", sep = ",", direction = "long"))

     sample
id    MER-1 MER-2 MER-3 MER-4 MER-5
  id1     1     0     1     1     0
  id2     0     0     0     0     1
  id3     0     1     0     0     0
  id4     0     1     1     1     1
  id5     0     0     1     0     0
  id6     0     0     0     0     1
```

Or using `cSplit_e` created exactly for this scenario (provided by @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1):

```
cSplit_e(dt, "sample", sep = ",", type = "character", fill = 0, drop = TRUE)
```

Comment: You should use `cSplit_e` for this purpose.

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 looks like a nice option, however, I cannot get it work on this data. `cSplit_e(dt, "sample", sep = ",", fill = 0)` throws me an error.

Comment: Add a `type = "character" ` in there...

Comment: @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 thank you, it is really a neat function :)